# How to deal with different kind of encoding in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

Working in Python 2.7 with this short script to use the VirusTotal API (the main point of this API is to upload files to scan in the virustotal site):

```
def scanAFile(fileToScan):
    host = "www.virustotal.com"
    selector = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan"
    fields = [("apikey", myPublicKey)]
    file_to_send = open(fileToScan, "rb").read()
    files = [("file", fileToScan, file_to_send)]
    json = postfile.post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files)

    return simplejson.loads(json)
```

I found the problem that for each file I want to upload I need to use different encoding or I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PythonDev/20150617_WW/agent_vt.py", line 139, in <module>
    scanQueue()
  File "/home/user/PythonDev/20150617_WW/agent_vt.py", line 76, in scanQueue
    jsonScan = scanAFile(fileToScan) #todo if file not found skip
  File "/home/user/PythonDev/20150617_WW/agent_vt.py", line 37, in scanAFile
    json = postfile.post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files)
  File "/home/user/PythonDev/20150617_WW/postfile.py", line 13, in post_multipart
    content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files)
  File "/home/user/PythonDev/20150617_WW/postfile.py", line 45, in encode_multipart_formdata
    body = CRLF.join(L)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The file postfile.py is given for virustotal on their website, and this is the function where is the encoding problem:

```
def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files):
    """
    fields is a sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.
    files is a sequence of (name, filename, value) elements for data to be uploaded as files
    Return (content_type, body) ready for httplib.HTTP instance
    """
    BOUNDARY = '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$'
    CRLF = '\r\n'
    L = []
    for (key, value) in fields:
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    for (key, filename, value) in files:
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (key, filename))
        L.append('Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(filename))
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
    L.append('')
    body = CRLF.join(L)
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY
    return content_type, body
```

As a temporary solution I add this piece of code in the beginning of the postfile.py:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

But is quite annoying to update this each time. Is there any way to deal with this problem?

Comment: `# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-` at top of postfile.py ?

Comment: @funkysayu, That declares the encoding of the *source file* and only matters if the source contains non-ASCII characters.  It's also incorrect if the source isn't actually saved in UTF-8.

Comment: @JohnSnow select the best answer

Answer (score 1):

try to use this lib for the encoding detection http://github.com/chardet/chardet

```
pip install chardet
```

then use it

```
import sys
import chardet

def scanAFile(fileToScan):
    code = chardet.detect(fileToScan)
    host = "www.virustotal.com"
    selector = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan"
    fields = [("apikey", myPublicKey)]
    file_to_send = open(fileToScan, "rb").read().decode(code['encoding'])
    files = [("file", fileToScan, file_to_send)]
    json = postfile.post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files)

    return simplejson.loads(json)
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I usually use `unicode_literas` from `__future__` lib.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this on the top of your python file and then execute.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```